# How do I save a jQuery CSS manipulation in a cookie?

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I got this code on my Wordpress Site which lets the user change the font-size of body {} when he clicks on one the 3 buttons which are generated through the HTML:

```
<button class='body_standard_font_size'>Standard</button>
<button class='body_medium_font_size'>medium</button>
<button class='body_big_font_size'>big</button>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_standard_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','100%');
});
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_medium_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','150%');
});
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_big_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','200%');
});
});
```

I have never worked with cookies before. How do I save that change in a cookie so  the font-size change is kept permanently or at least during the session?

@Sleek Geek (sorry, mispelled your name before ;)

I am trying to install the jQuery Cookie from Github.
It says I should include the script after my jQuery library.
This is how I enqueued my already existing jQuery script in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_scripts' );
function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }
```

Now I tried adding the jQuery cookie below in the same hook, so it looks like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_scripts' );
function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }

function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery.cookie',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cookie.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }
```

But the page doesn't load anymore. I don't even know if I adjusted the code properly...

Comment: you could use session storage. and just store the last clicked name.

Comment: any errors in your console or error-log ?

Comment: yes: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: @Daniel as I understood session storage only is suitable for IE 8 and up, but I would like to support the old IE as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage (does not expire) or sessionStorage (expires when the browser is closed);

So you can try s.th like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.body_standard_font_size').on('click', function() {
        $('body').css('font-size','100%');
        localStorage.setItem('font-size', '100%');
    });

   ... //equivalent to the other click-functions

   //and on page load:
   var fontsize = localStorage.getItem('font-size');
   $('body').css('font-size', fontsize);
});
```

To refactor your code: there is no need to wrap every click-event in `$(document).ready()`. You can wrap all function with one ready-handler

I don't know if you can edit your html, but you can tighten your code a bit, here my suggestion:

HTML

```
<button class='body_standard_font_size fontsize' data-size="100%">Standard</button>
<button class='body_medium_font_size fontsize' data-size="150%">medium</button>
<button class='body_big_font_size fontsize' data-size="200%">big</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fontsize;
    $('.fontsize').on('click', function() {
        fontsize = $(this).data('size');
        $('body').css('font-size',fontsize);
        localStorage.setItem('font-size', fontsize);
    });

    fontsize = localStorage.getItem('font-size');
    $('body').css('font-size', fontsize);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9wdL6kqp/)

If you want to use cookies you can set a cookie with:

```
document.cookie = "font-size=100%";
```

and getting it with

```
document.cookie;
```

But here you have to split the cookie in its parts to get the actual font-size, so I ould recommend to use the webStorage.

**Reference**

[web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Note: This is support by all major browser and IE >= 8

Comment: Hey empiric thank you for your detailed answer.
Accessiblity is very important for the site, the old IEs should be supported as well...

When I tried to put all the jQuery inside one .ready handler I couldnt get it to work properly. Im really new to jQuery and Javascript, this is my first piece of code which I didnt even write myself

Answer (score 0):

Study the approach below and adjust as needed.

```
function fontExpand(){        
        var fontExpand = $('body').css('font-size','100%');
        $.cookie('font-grew', true, {path: '/'});

    }
     console.log('my font grew.');
    // - checks the font size above
    if($.cookie('font-grew')){
        console.log('font grows automatically...');
        fontExpand();

    }

        // Increase the font size on click
    $('.body_standard_font_size').click(function () {

           fontExpand();

    });
```

Comment: Hey Sleek Geek just trying to kindly ask again if you could briefly check the edited post after @Sleek Geek and eventually help me out.

Comment: I'll look at it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<?php
 if (!isset($_POST['font'])) {
  echo "wrong post parameters - aborted";
 } else {
  setcookie("fontsize", $_POST['font'], time()+3600); // save cookie for 1 h
  echo "Font saved";
 }
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>
  <?php 
   // define standard fontsize
   $standardFontSize = "16";
   
   // check if cookie is set, when yes -> load it, if not -> load standard
   if (isset($_COOKIE['fontsize'])) {
    echo $_COOKIE['fontsize'];
   } else {
    echo $standardFontSize;
   }
  ?>
  </h2>
  
  <br />
  
  <button class="changefont" data-font="standard">Standard</button>
  <button class="changefont" data-font="small">Small</button>
  <button class="changefont" data-font="big">Big</button>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".changefont").click(function() {
   var font = $(this).data("font");
   
   $("h2").html(font);
   
   $.ajax({
    url: "fontsave.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: "font="+font,
    success: function(html) {
     alert(html);
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```